# CVS Branching + Binary Files

Tags: eclipse, cvs, binaryfiles, branching-and-merging

I'm using CVS through the eclipse plugin. I have a .fla and a .swf file which I have committed in CVS. I created a new branch and made changes in the .fla and swf files and committed them on the new branch. I want to merge the new branch with it's root branch and switch back to the root branch but CVS is complaining and not letting do so. I am able to commit files on the development branch, but how do i merge and then switch to the root branch?

This is happening because both .fla and .swf are binary files. I know binary files are can't be merged. But I do want to **overwrite** the fla & swf on the root branch with the new fla & swf from the new branch. How do I go about doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did and it worked.

Development branch is where I code.
Head is where I commit my stable releases.

1. Switch to `HEAD`
2. Right Click > Team > Merge
3. In the pop up that opens, select `development` (branch in which you coded) as the end tag.
4. select `Root_development` (this is the parent of the development branch, for me it was `HEAD`) as the start tag.
5. Preview merge (which is already pre-selected)
6. In the synchronization view that opens up, **right click on the binary file > overwrite**.
7. Done!
8. Commit to the `HEAD` or the parent branch

Answer (score 1):

If this is the first and last time you are doing this then the most simple way is just to copy your files and commit them again to the root.

Or use this command to make CVS doing this for you. (do it in your root working directory)

```
cvs update -j <my_branch> <my_files>
```

This command works only for the very fist change in your branch.
If you need to do merge in future many times you can use this set of commands to avoid conflicts:

```
cvs update -j <my_branch_last_join_tag_name> -j <my_branch> <my_files>
cvs tag -r <my_branch> -F <my_branch_last_join_tag_name> <my_files>
```

Comment: I'll be switching between branches. All development will be done on the development branch and stable releases will be committed on the head, including binary files. How do i do the switching using the eclipse plugin?